# Como iterar un array dependiendo del ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Tengo un problema, estoy utilizando React-Redux y mostrando una lista de objetos con una poca cantidad de elementos:

```
{"id": 0, ...}, 
{"id": 1, ...}, 
{"id": 2, ...},
 .... , 
{"id": n, ...}]
```

Cada objeto dentro del array tiene unos 50 elementos, **en mi primer pantalla estoy mostrando solo un par de ellas**, pero quiero crear una segunda pantalla donde, **seleccionando cada objeto respetando su `id`, me muestre más información de ese objeto** (es decir, sus demás elementos).

Intenté iterar dentro del array con *.filter* y que me traiga la información según el ID del cono, pero tendría que poner a mano cuál es el objeto que quiero mostrar.

```
  const currentCono = useSelector((state) => state.centrales.currentCono);

  const getObj = (id) => {
    return currentCono.filter((cono) => cono.id === id);
  };

  getObj(3).map(cono => (...))
```

Como ven, tengo que poner el id en el código, yo quiero que seleccionando mi objeto en particular me traiga la información de ese mismo `cono`.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que estás utilizando [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) en vez de [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

El método `filter` de javascript retorna un arreglo con los valores que cumplan la condición implementada en el callback.

Entonces por eso estás recibiendo en tu `getObj(3)` algo parecido a un arreglo de un solo índice:

```
[{ id: 3, ...props }]
```

Mientras que el método `find` devuelve el primer valor que cumpla la condición implementada en el callback:

```
{ id: 3, ...props }
```

Entonces, aclarando los conceptos anteriores, podrías simplemente solucionarlo así:

```js
const conos = [{
    id: 0,
    prop: 'value'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    prop: 'value'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    prop: 'value'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    prop: 'value',
    otherProp: 'otherValue'
  }
];

const getObj = (id) => conos.find(cono => cono.id === id);
const foundCono = getObj(4);

console.log(foundCono.id);
```